# change the port 9090 of Openfire 'Admin Console' after installation

Tags: server, xmpp, openfire

How to change default port 9090 of Openfire 'Admin Console' by means of `conf/openfire.xml` after installation ?

I tried this config:

```
<setup>false</setup>

<adminConsole> 
    <port>8080</port>  
    <securePort>-1</securePort> 
</adminConsole>
```

with restarting server's service `service openfire restart` but it always listens to 9090 and 9091.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just log to the admin console then Edit Server Properties in the server information page.
You find a list of used ports that you can change (admin, c2s, s2s,...)